# Which SIP-Client or SIP Phone is supported by Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS or 19.10?

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, software-recommendation, 19.10, sip

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu and it's hard to stop loving the new change. I need help in regards to finding an SIP phone which is compatible with
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS or 19.10, and including a recording feature. I researched on Google, Ubuntu 14 supports SFL but that's missing latest version while searching in Ubuntu software store.

Comment: twinkie is a good one

Answer (score 0):

Hello and Welcome to Linux.

I found an outdated list for Softphones for Ubuntu

[Community Help Wiki: SoftPhone](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftPhone)

[Download Jami for GNU/Linux](https://jami.net/download-jami-linux/) Note, that was issue with https://ring.cx should redirecting to https://jami.net/

The software looks easy to use and has the recording capability.
You can download the *.deb package and install it.